# Recommenden Debian version for developing

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am using for the first time Beaglebone black. Whe you choose a Linux OS version almost always people recomend you use the previous one before the last one because it is free of bugs.

My question is: I need to apply the same philosophy in beaglebone (Choose the previous one version 8.7 instead of 9.3 the last one today 23/02/2018)?

Beaglebone web page recommend me use the last one 9.3, so that just amplify my doubts.

I want to work over a bug free version with well supoorted drviers for my master thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend going with *Debian 9.3*. The Debian side is not what you need to worry about, it's extremely stable.

There are some aspects that you should be aware of, due to a *lot* of various write-ups being out there.

- DT overlays get applied in U-Boot (cf. uenv.txt)
- uenv.txt lives in /boot nowadays, not on the FAT partition
- If any write-up mentions a 3.8 kernel, disregard it. It will be horribly outdated
- There are userspace mechanisms now to control pin muxing and pin options
- Avoid `/dev/mem` there be *many* dragons!

The question you will need to ask yourself though is which Linux kernel version you will want to run. That will also depend on your actual use case for the Hardware. It's impossible to give a recommendation without knowing more. One very important aspect though is that you *MUST NOT* choose a RealTime Linux kernel without understanding the impact that it will have (actually making a lot of things *slower*, cf. [Steven's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UY7hQjEW34&t=1811s))